# I have Css override issue on my plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="theme/myjquerystyle.css">
    </head>
    <body>

<iframe>
     <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
        <head>
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="plugin/myjquerystyle.css">
        </head>
        <body>
        My Plugins page
        </body>
    </html>
</iframe>

</body>
</html>
```

As you can see above code i have create a html page inside the html page.
My problem is that theme/myjquerystyle.css override my plugin/myjquerystyle.css
How can I give a priority to my plugin/jquerystyle.css file apply to my page.
Any solution

Comment: CSS priority is defined by the other in which they rules are declared. Last defined thus has highest priority. Can you modify the contents of the iframe?

Comment: One way you can do is giving `!important` to all the properties of `CSS` in your 2nd `StyleSheet`

Comment: Hi, xaviert I have make lots of change in plugin/myjquerystyle.css css file

Comment: it is not possible to add !importan to all css

Answer (score 0):

> I believe we cannot define inside iframe (never tried so) however we can acheive this via Javascript where we can append styles to iframe section via:

```
$('iframe').load( function() {
    $('iframe').contents().find("head")
      .append($("<style type='text/css'>  .myclass{display:none;}  </style>"));
});
```

> Else you can also try by adding styles to individual elements inside
>   iframe as:

```
iframe.$('mydiv').addClassName('Tablewithborder');
```

Hope it helps.